# Aren't HashMap keys and values unique?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have got a HashMap in my code which contains unique values. 
When I add a new value to this collection, the container changes all values to the new one.

I want to know if this collection keeps unique values or not and what is the problem in my code. Because I'm using the same collection in another class but I don't have this problem.

```
//HashMaps filled with datas from JDialog 
HashMap<Integer,Activity> activity_hashmap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer,String> ad_activity_table_hashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

Here is the method which adds data to the HashMap:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("ADD");
    int activity_amount = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField17.getText());
    int activity_contract_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField19.getText());
    int activity_document_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField13.getText());
    String activity_st = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int activity_number = -1;
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,String> entry : ad_activity_table_hashmap.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getValue() == jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()){
            activity_number = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    if (jTextField17.getText().equals("") || jTextField19.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "لطفا همه فيلد ها را پر كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (!FinancialDocumentsJFrame.checkDocumentAmountText(jTextField17.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي مبلغ فعاليت نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (!FinancialDocumentsJFrame.checkNumberText(jTextField19.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره قرارداد نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==-1){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "شرح فعاليت انتخاب نشده است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!activity_hashmap.isEmpty()){  
        if (activity_number == -1){
            System.out.println("Error in Activity Number");
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "اشكال در شماره فعاليت لطفا دوباره تلاش كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
           boolean exists = activity_hashmap.containsKey(activity_number); 
           if (exists){
               JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي موجود است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
           } 
           else if ((count_activities_amount + activity_amount)>Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField16.getText())){
               JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "جمع مبالغ با مبلغ سند نمي خواند لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
           }
           else {
               jButton4ActionPerformed_count++;
               Activity act = new Activity(activity_st, activity_number, activity_amount, activity_contract_number, activity_document_number);
               System.out.println("Initialize");
               act.printactivitytInformation();
               activity_hashmap.put(activity_number, act);
               System.out.println("Add to hashmap");
               activity_hashmap.get(activity_number).printactivitytInformation();
               count_activities_amount += activity_amount;
               Object[] row = { activity_contract_number, Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField16.getText())-count_activities_amount,  activity_amount, activity_st, activity_document_number };
               DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
               model.addRow(row);
               row_count++;
           }
        }

    }
    else {
        jButton4ActionPerformed_count++;
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);
        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        jTextField19.setEnabled(false);
        //System.out.println("Error Activity");

        //System.out.println("Error Before Activity");

        Activity act = new Activity(activity_st, activity_number, activity_amount, activity_contract_number, activity_document_number);
        System.out.println("Initialize");
        act.printactivitytInformation();

        //System.out.println("Error Before Activity Adding");

        activity_hashmap.put(activity_number, act);
        System.out.println("Add to hashmap");
        activity_hashmap.get(activity_number).printactivitytInformation();
        //System.out.println("Error After Activity Adding");

        count_activities_amount += activity_amount;
        Object[] row = { activity_contract_number, Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField16.getText())-count_activities_amount,  activity_amount, activity_st, activity_document_number };
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.addRow(row);
        row_count++;

        }
    jTextField18.setText(count_activities_amount.toString());
    if (count_activities_amount == Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField16.getText())){
        jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    }
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,Activity> entry : activity_hashmap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("ENumber2: "+entry.getValue().getActivityNumber());
            System.out.println("EName2: "+entry.getValue().getActivityStatement());

    }


}
```

Here is what happens : when ever I add a new Activity to **activity_hashmap.put(activity_number, act);** it changes all values to the last inserted value.

```
ADD
ENumber2: 10114
EName2: سايت سازي 

ADD
ENumber2: 10112
EName2: فروش نرم افزار بنيادي
ENumber2: 10112
EName2: فروش نرم افزار بنيادي 

ADD 
ENumber2: 10113
EName2: پشتيباني نرم افزار بنيادي
ENumber2: 10113
EName2: پشتيباني نرم افزار بنيادي
ENumber2: 10113
EName2: پشتيباني نرم افزار بنيادي

ADD 
ENumber2: 10118
EName2: تجهيزات كاربردي خاص***
ENumber2: 10118
EName2: تجهيزات كاربردي خاص***
ENumber2: 10118
EName2: تجهيزات كاربردي خاص***
ENumber2: 10118
EName2: تجهيزات كاربردي خاص***
```

Note: The print lines are for my own debugging.

Comment: Only keys are unique in a map

Comment: as you have checked, only keys are unique

Comment: Are the properties of your Activity class static?

Comment: "Because I'm using the same collection in another class but I don't have this problem. " Maybe in this case you were using a different class that does not properly implement `equals` and `hashcode`, thus using the default. This way, objects that appear to be the same get different slots in the hash map.

Comment: Are you sure the root of the problem is in this method?  It doesn't seem from the code that the lines that add in the new Activity would cause the previously stored ones to change.  If you debug it just before and after the line where it adds the new Activity, I imagine you will correctly see the new record being added differently.  If that is the case - maybe you have some kind of TableModelListener that is then altering the activity_hashmap when the new row is added to the model?

Comment: Yes @Eran Can you explain more about static variables? I'm not very familiar with them and I don't no why I have used it.

Comment: @Sparrow7000 Please see my answer

Comment: It worked. THANKS @Eran

Answer (score 2):

Since the members of your Activity class are static (as mentioned in your comment), all instances of the `Activity` class will have the same values for these properties (since a static member is shared by all instances of the class). Therefore you see the same values in all the values of your Map.

Change the members of your Activity class to be non static (i.e. remove the static keyword) and your problem will be solved.